# aws sdk - listing security groups in c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

Here is how I'm trying to list amazon (aws) security groups of VPC using AWSSDK in c#:

```
    var ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
    var dsgRequest = new DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest();
    var dsgResponse = ec2Client.DescribeSecurityGroups(dsgRequest);
    List<SecurityGroup> mySGs = dsgResponse.SecurityGroups;
    foreach (SecurityGroup item in mySGs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Existing security group: " + item.GroupId);
    }
```

It only displays the default amazon security group while when I login to amazon via browser, I see lots of company security groups.
Any idea why this does not list them all?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you didn't set a `RegionEndpoint`.

I modified your code slightly, and was able to enumerate my security groups:

```
var config = new AmazonEC2Config { RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2};
var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

using (var client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonEC2Client(credentials, config))
{
    var dsgRequest = new DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest();
    var dsgResponse = client.DescribeSecurityGroups(dsgRequest);
    List<SecurityGroup> mySGs = dsgResponse.SecurityGroups;
    foreach (SecurityGroup item in mySGs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Existing security group: " + item.GroupId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I had actually set the end point properly. I ran the same code that I had a few days later and it worked. It must have been amazon services gone down or something like that.